# How to redirect to particular URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect if user open with

1 `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

2 `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

3 `http://example.com/user/(anystring)` to `https://www.example.com/user/(anystring)`

4 `http://www.example.com/user/(anystring)` to `https://www.example.com/user/(anystring)`

I've tried this `htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\/user\/*$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com\/user\/*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/user\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

3rd and 4th is not working properly, `(anystring)` is not accessible, I'm going to set `COOKIE`, but its not available after redirection.

Comment: And your question is what?

Comment: Ah, you probably get an endless redirection loop, I assume?

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS This article

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this to a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

And the test for the host name is actually only required if you have other virtual hosts based in the same rule set that you do *not* want to rewrite.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).